# convert string to DWORD_PTR and DWORD_PTR to string

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have function where parameter is DWORD_PTR and I need to pass string in to this func (convert string to DWORD_PTR) and then I need to read it inside func(convert DWORD_PTR to string)

```
std::string myStr = "some string";
myFunc(DWORD_PTR string)
```

How I can do this?

p.s. Lets skip questions like 'why you using DWORD_PTR as parameter?'
becouse I need it.

Comment: `myFunc((DWORD_PTR)myStr.c_str());` If `myFunc` is thread function, ensure that `myStr` exists when the function starts. Inside `myFunc` cast `DWORD_PTR` to `const char*`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast <DWORD_PTR>(&myStr)` and vice versa

Comment: Asking us to skip that question is rather short sighted. If we cannot ask that question, how can we work out how you intend to perform the conversion. Instead of concealing information from us you would do well to open up.

Comment: Knowing why you're using `DWORD_PTR` as a parameter is essential in knowing how to correctly marshal / pass the data.

Comment: A `string` is not a `DWORD` and it's not a pointer, so there is no single obvious conversion between them. Give some example values and what you'd like the conversion to return.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
myFunc(DWORD_PTR data) {
    std::string local_copy{ reinterpret_cast<char*>(data) };
}

std::string data = "some string";
myFunc( reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(data.c_str()) );
```

These work by transmitting the address where the data is, as a pointer (and converted to DWORD ptr). You can do it in different ways, but you didn't specify (you could for example transmit the address of a std::string instead).

> p.s. Lets skip questions like 'why you using DWORD_PTR as parameter?' becouse I need it.

Ok, I will skip the question - but I think the answer to the question is "because you have the [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)" ... just saying'.

Comment: reiterpret_cast should be reinterpret_cast....typo error

Answer (score 0):

```
1.calling myFunc((DWORD_PTR)&myStr);
2.inside the function: std::string& str = *(std::string*)string;
```

Comment: Given the limited information in the question, this is a perfectly legitimate answer.